# How to send $_GET by Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send an $_GET['CategoryID'] trought ajax to call in the destination file getdata.php and I can't make it work, I don't find the perfect info here. I know that I am really noob, but I am trying really hard to learn.

I been trying a lot of different code and it still not working.

```
<button type="button" name="btn_more" data-vid="<?php echo $stockID; ?>" id="btn_more" class="btn btn-success form-control">Ver Mais</button>
<input class="form-control" id="PresentCategoryID" name="PresentCategoryID" data-cat="<?php echo $_GET['categoryID']; ?>" value="<?php echo $_GET['categoryID']; 


<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $(document).on('click', '#btn_more', function(){  
           var last_video_id = $(this).data("vid");
               var PresentCategoryID= ('PresentCategoryID');
           $('#btn_more').html("<div class=loader></div>");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"getdata.php",  
                method:"POST",
                    data:{
                         last_video_id:last_video_id,
                         PresentCategoryID:PresentCategoryID},  
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     if(data != '')  
                     {  
                          $('#remove_row').remove();  
                          $('#result').append(data);  
                     }  
                     else  
                     {  
         $('#btn_more').html("No Data");  
           }  
         }  
      });  
   });
 });  
</script>
```

My objective it's to call the categoryID in the getdata.php, like this,

```
<?php  
$output = '';  
$stockID = '';
$PresentCategoryID = '';
sleep(1);  
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
include 'includes/rating.inc.php';
$sql = "SELECT stock.stockID, stock.name, stock.marca, stock.origem, stock.categoryID, stock.thumbnail, category.name AS catname FROM stock JOIN category ON stock.categoryID=category.categoryID WHERE stock.categoryID='$PresentCategoryID' AND stockID > ".$_POST['last_video_id']." LIMIT 4";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var PresentCategoryID= ('PresentCategoryID')
```

should be

```
var PresentCategoryID= $('#PresentCategoryID').val();
```

You need to use `$` to select the element, add the `#` prefix to use it as an ID, and `.val()` to get the value of the input.

Comment: Thank you bro! I just did it!.

Answer (score 0):

hey check this answer which will help your problem

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#btn_more', function() {
        var last_video_id = $(this).data("vid");
        var PresentCategoryID = ('#PresentCategoryID').val();
        $('#btn_more').html("<div class=loader></div>");
        var data = {
            last_video_id,
            PresentCategoryID
        };

        $.get('getdata.php', JSON.stringify(data)).done(response => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response != '') {
                $('#remove_row').remove();
                $('#result').append(response);
            } else {
                $('#btn_more').html("No Data");
            }

        }).fail(() => {
            console.log("Something went wrong");
        });
    });

});
```

PHP SCRIPT

```
<? php
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
include 'includes/rating.inc.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
//if you using get request
//recommended way to get the data use the mysqlconn->real_escape_string($_GET['last_video_id']);
    $last_video_id = $_GET['last_video_id'];
    $PresentCategoryID = $_GET['PresentCategoryID'];
    sleep(1);
    $sql = "SELECT stock.stockID, stock.name, stock.marca, stock.origem, stock.categoryID, stock.thumbnail, category.name AS catname FROM stock JOIN category ON stock.categoryID=category.categoryID WHERE stock.categoryID='$PresentCategoryID' AND stockID='$$last_video_id'";
    " LIMIT 4";
} else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    //if you using post request then in jquery remove $.get to just $.post 
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
    $last_video_id = $data['last_video_id'];
    $PresentCategoryID = $data['PresentCategoryID'];
}
```

Comment: It didn't work right like that, but thank you, it was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

you want to send via 'GET' but you use the method 'POST'.

Best regards
MrKampf

Comment: suggestions, queries can be placed as comment.. if you don't have enough reputation to comment, try giving a solution rather than a comment.

Comment: It's a solution, his question is, how he can use $_GET, with current code he must be use $_POST :-)